# Export R plot via svg() without zooming

Tags: r, svg, plot

In R, I am generating a large network graph of 100 nodes via the following code:

```
library(igraph)

data<-data.frame(c(1:500))

relations<-data.frame(from=c(sample(1:500,500,replace=T)),to=c(sample(1:500,500,replace=T)))

g<-graph_from_data_frame(d=relations,vertices = data,directed=T)

l<-layout_with_fr(g)

l <- norm_coords(l, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xmin=-2, xmax=2)

plot(g, edge.arrow.size=.2, edge.curved=0,vertex.color="orange", vertex.frame.color="#555555",vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.cex=.7,rescale=F,layout=l)
```

This produces a plot that looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqPBE.jpg
Obviously this is not ideal, as the graph does not fit in the picture.  So, I tried exporting the plot to an SVG file via:

```
svg(width=20, height=20)
plot(g, edge.arrow.size=.2, edge.curved=0,vertex.color="orange", vertex.frame.color="#555555",vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.cex=.7,rescale=F,layout=l) 
dev.off()
```

This produces an SVG file that appears zoomed in, and I can't zoom out to see the whole graph....even though I didn't adjust the coordinates or scale the graph differently (I believe).  Here is a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnTo.jpg

How can I export the entire graph nicely to an SVG file?  I am not committed to SVG *per se* but this seemed like a good approach.

**EDIT: added igraph library and line to define my layout algorithm**

Comment: When I try to recreate this issue I get an error at `l <- norm_coords(l, ymin=-2, ymax=2, xmin=-2, xmax=2)` `l` is undefined.

Comment: @alaybourn ah sorry, I skipped a step to define l.  Added that into my original post + included igraph library at the top.  You should be able to recreate now.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing rescale=T in your plotting function produce what you expect?

```
plot(g, edge.arrow.size=.2, edge.curved=0,vertex.color="orange", vertex.frame.color="#555555",vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.cex=.7,rescale=T,layout=l)
```

Comment: if I set rescale=T, the nodes get really bunched up: https://imgur.com/5jB8H9I     I'm looking to get these nodes sufficiently spaced out.

Comment: got it.  the problem is with your plotting function and whatever layout you are choosing, not the svg export.  Basically the svg just exports whatever you see on the plot to a vectorized file.  The format is better if you want to resize later, but it wont help if your plot window is too small.  I haven't used igraph before, so I probably can't get you any closer to a solution, sorry!

Comment: I figured as much.  It is just strange that the svg export makes it appear more zoomed in (with the same plotting/layout), than it appears in an rconsole window using just plot().  Thanks.